# Possibilities to encrypt/decrypt single files in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, encryption

Is there a way to encrypt and decrypt singles files in the Google Drive web interface?

I am aware of encryption possibilities for the Google Drive client. But I need encryption for files that I want to access from the Google Drive web interface when being on the go and not on my personal machine.

Comment: Your question will do better here if you focus on the problem you're trying to solve, rather than asking us to help you find an app that fits your criteria.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think I described my problem. I want to decrypt encrpyted files through the Google Drive Webinterface because I sometimes need these files when not being at my personal machine where I have access to a local decryption software.